Missing Numpy in compiled Python script
I recently finished my first program in Python and I want to share it with my friends to use but when I compile the script and try to run the executable it says I'm missing 'numpy'.
Numpy is not explicitly used in the script, but it is a dependency of Pandas. I have tried to include it with '--hidden import' and I have tried to explicitly include it in my script. I have also tried to create a new .venv and reinstall all modules but numpy is still missing when compiled; it runs fine in Pycharm.
Pyinstaller prompt (.venv):  
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "model_df.csv:." --add-data "player_index_df.csv:." --add-data "court_surface_index_df.csv:." UserInterface.py

Modules I'm using:
import pandas as pd  
import sqlite3  
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split   
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier  
import hashlib  
import os  
import sys  
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QApplication, QLineEdit  
from PredictionModel import ModelOperations

Error:
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: No module named 'numpy'

https://github.com/Snomaskin/ATP-Winner-Predictor

Does this answer your question? Pyinstaller with pandas and numpy, exe throws error at runtime

Note that the linked question (and answer) is several years old, and versions of NumPy and PyInstaller are probably more recent for your case, so the answer in the linked question may not be appropriate anymore.

I couldn't get that old version to work on my Apple silicon. The earliest I can get to work is 1.21.1 and it throws the same error when the code is compiled unfortunately.
